# Standard Tomcat libraries in IDEA 14

Tags: jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea, jar

In IDEA 14 (Ultimate) after the creation of the module (Web Application) start to write a scriptlet in jsp. Auto-substitution sees standard objects of jsp (out, session, and so on.). But did not sees their methods while I manually add to module servlet-api.jar and jsp-api.jar from tomcat libs.

This is normal behavior? If not, then why it's happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved by:
Project Settings -> Modules -> Dependencies -> Add Libraries -> Select application Server Libraries.